# Why is there insertOrThrow but no updateOrThrow or deleteOrThrow?

Tags: android

I am creating android app that uses SQLite database. Looking at the SQLiteDatabase class I found that there is a method called `insertOrThrow()` which is similar to `insert()` but with one important difference - if insert fails it will throw exception and app will die (if not catched). I am using `insertOrThrow()` in the initial stage of the development because it draws my attention to SQL errors in a very noticeable way, i.e. app dies.
I am just curious: Why is there no `updateOrThrow()`, `deleteOrThrow()`, etc... I've tried to google for info but did not found anything...

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be because `insert` and `replace` are intended to affect a single row. It might make more sense to throw if something bad (like your row wasn't actually inserted due to a constraint) happens here.

For `delete` and `update` multiple rows are affected, and it isn't abnormal for zero rows to be affected by these queries.

In either case, exceptions will be thrown for a variety of reasons like a malformed query or a non-existent table.

Comment: From that point of view - yes, it makes sense.
Initially I was thinking that InsertOrThrow() is useful when some constraint may get violated like uniqueness for example, that is why I was wondering why there is no updateOrThrow()...